# Mac equivalent to .Net SerialPort.ReadExisting()

Tags: objective-c, vb.net, macos, cocoa, serial-port

I'm working on porting a VB program to the PC. It uses serial communication to interact with a physical device. I have a version up and running on the Mac using `ORSSerialPort`. However, once piece of the VB library that is great is the `SerialPort.ReadExisting()` function. This essentially reads any messages and discards them.

Has anyone built something similar on the Mac side? I've tried pulling out the ORSSerialPort into a function to directly read values (see below). However, unless I send a message I receive a null response. The readExisting function would be great for a scenario when things get a little out of alignment such as:

I send a message "Message1" to the device and nothing happens (was expecting Response1). 
I send a message "Message2" to the device and receive: "Response1" instead of "Response2"

I'd like to detect this, call an equivalent to `SerialPort.readExisting()` since Response2 is the next to be found if I continue.

My read function:

```
-(NSString *) directRead
{
    // Read Directly
    int localPortFD = self.fileDescriptor;
    struct timeval timeout;
    int result=0;

    fd_set localReadFDSet;
    FD_ZERO(&localReadFDSet);
    FD_SET(localPortFD, &localReadFDSet);

    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    timeout.tv_usec = 100000; // Check to see if port closed every 100ms

    result = select(localPortFD+1, &localReadFDSet, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    if (!self.isOpen) return nil; // Port closed while select call was waiting
    if (result < 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"No Data To Read");
    }

    if (result == 0 || !FD_ISSET(localPortFD, &localReadFDSet)) return nil;

    // Data is available
    char buf[1024];
    long lengthRead = read(localPortFD, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if (lengthRead>0)
    {
        NSData *readData = [NSData dataWithBytes:buf length:lengthRead];
        if (readData != nil)
            return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:readData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

You would think just doing:

```
NSString *result = nil;
do 
{
   result = [serialPort directRead];
   NSLog(@"Past Message is: %@", result);
} while(result != nil);
```

Would flush out the messages. However, it acts as if there aren't any messages. However, if I call sendData:Message1 again I'd still see Response2 show up (in the above scenario).

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a little trouble following exactly what you're trying to do here, but in any case, it's something you'll have to implement at a higher level than ORSSerialPort or the POSIX serial read functions. ORSSerialPort will tell you any time bytes are available, as reported by the underlying standard POSIX file APIs it uses. So, there's nothing to "flush" from its perspective. If you get a response you were not expecting, e.g. a response to an "old" request, there's no way at all for the serial port to know that, it's up to your code to figure it out.

Something like this:

```
- (void)serialPort:(ORSSerialPort *)serialPort didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    if (![self dataIsResponseToLatestRequest:data]) return; // Try again next time around

    // Process a valid (expected response)
}
```

This raises a couple other issues. You can't be guaranteed that data will come in "whole packets". The serial hardware, low level serial APIs, and ORSSerialPort have no way of knowing what a whole packet looks like, and therefore just deliver data a bit at a time as it arrives. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21608305/344733) for more on that. So, it's up to you to buffer incoming data and assemble it into packets.

If you need to match requests you sent with responses coming in, you have to do that yourself. (sounds like you're really already doing this).

Lastly, if you're only receiving "Response1" after sending "Message2", this leads me to think there's a problem with the device on the other side of the connection not responding to requests properly. It would probably be worth fixing that, if you can (assuming it's your hardware/software).

Comment: As an aside, these general issues have been on my mind lately, and I've thought about enhancing ORSSerialPort to make it easier to deal with them. Please feel free to comment on [this issue](https://github.com/armadsen/ORSSerialPort/issues/17) if you have any thoughts.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The hardware we're using may have an issue but we are unable to change that at the moment. However, the VB or C# SerialPort.ReadExisting() solves all the issues we have on the PC. As for the packet handling that's working just fine. It's just sometimes we need to clear out everything that's left behind. Would this be done at a lower level with the write() command?

Comment: I think the fundamental issue is that there's nothing to clear out. Neither the low level serial code, nor ORSSerialPort buffer and hold any data. If the port was set for canonical mode, data would come in line by line, and a missing newline might cause the behavior you describe. ORSSerialPort explicitly uses raw/non-canonical mode, so data is delivered as it comes in. When you get "Response1", after "Message2", "Response2" will also subsequently come in unless the device at the other end hasn't sent it. Are you using canonical mode on Windows? Feel free to email me to discuss further.

Comment: Really I think it comes down to a design issue. I ended up redesigning the message system to send a message and then poll in a block until the response shows up (need to code some sort of timeout still) but that is working great. A manual "direct read" just gets too screwed up. Thanks for the great library by the way!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working! The Github issue linked in my first comment is an enhancement request to add a built in request/wait-for-response API to ORSSerialPort. If you're interested in progress on that, feel free to subscribe to updates on that issue.